# django manage.py settings default

Tags: python, django

I have a `settings.py` file and a `dev_settings.py` file that I use to override some values for dev purposes.  Everytime I run the `./manage.py` command, I have to specify `--settings=whatever.local_settings`.  This becomes very tedious to do every time and I am trying to find a way to force manage.py to load my dev_settings.py file every by default so that I don't have to type that long argument every time I want to run a command.

I have tried setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, however, it appears that manage.py overrides this option.

Is it possible to make this happen or am I doomed to always specify that argument?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`manage.py` sets path to settings for you, that's why it's ignoring `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` (it's basically just script that wraps around `django-admin.py`).

There are 2 easy ways to fix your problem:

1. set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and use `django-admin.py` to run all commands instead of `manage.py`. This is even better if you use [vitualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
2. copy `manage.py` and name it `local.py` (that's the name in my case) and rename all `settings` mentions to `dev_settings`.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
import imp

try:
    import settings_local
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings_local.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings_local)
```

You can run all commands by `./local.py` now.

Comment: I went the django-admin.py route!  I didn't even realize you could do that.  I for some reason thought django-admin.py was just for creating new projects.  Silly me...

Answer (score 3):

The way this is typically done is you have `settings.py` with all settings that are common between environments (things like INSTALLED_APPS, etc.). Then, you have something like `settings_local.py`, that defines settings particular to the environment in context. You then import `settings_local.py` in `settings.py`.

```
# settings.py

from settings_local import *
```

`settings.py` gets added to your source code repository, but `settings_local.py` does not. (However, you would normally add something like `settings_local.py.example` to the repo.)

When you first move your app over to production, for example, you pull down the code base from your repo. You then copy `settings_local.py.example` to `settings_local.py` and make any necessary environment specific changes.

You then have separate `settings_local.py` files in each environment, and it all just works.

Comment: I think @intargc is playing around with different technique (http://toastdriven.com/blog/2010/jan/05/better-local-settings/). It's actually easier to extend settings this way.

Comment: Well, his complaint is the downside to that approach. I don't necessarily disagree with the logic of that approach, but it's mostly semantic, and comes with the cost of having to constant specify the settings file to use. All things being equal, simpler is better, so I say the traditional approach of importing the local settings at the end is the superior.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really equal. When I tried to play around with extending (not overriding) of variables using this technique, it just refused to work. That was some time ago tho. I use the second one since then and it works well for me (simplifying it by creating new manage.py as described in my answer).

Comment: Oddly enough, we had it this way and it worked great. However, we had a training session with Jacob Kaplan-Moss and he recommended that this way be avoided for a few reasons.  So we all decided to heed his advice and go the route we're doing now.

Comment: Well, I guess I can't argue with the Jacob ;), but in typical fashion the Django devs imposed a best practice and didn't go so far as to actually make it easy to follow. In my opinion, if it should be the practice to follow, the core team should have worked in a way to support it out of the box rather than requiring people to do something like modify manage.py `</soapbox>`.

Comment: I actually agree with you very much.  I find it to be a terrible idea personally, but he his reasons convinced some other devs on my team to go that route so now I'm stuck with this.  Problem was that when we had it the way you suggested, it worked just fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can make a bash alias by adding these lines to your .bash_profile file:

```
mymanage()
{
python manage.py $1 --settings=settings_debug
}
alias mng=mymanage
```

Then when you run this command:

```
mng runserver
```

settings_debug.py file will be used for settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use django-admin.py with that environment variable. Commands are interchangeable, only django-admin.py doesn't override the variable you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

If a settings file is common to all installation, you can just import it e.g.

```
from settings_local import *
```

but usually settings_local are changed and tweaked per installation and as my installation script directly copy files to target sites (without worrying what is local what is not), which mean settings_local may get overwritten, to avoid that I just keep settings_local in parent folder of the installation target and manually import it in settings.py e.g.

```
local_settings_file = os.path.join(prevFolder, "settings_local.py")
if os.path.exists(local_settings_file):
    execfile(local_settings_file)
```